# "undefined method `require_rspec_core' for RSpec::Support:Module" during running migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, during running migration I get rake aborted!

> NoMethodError: undefined method `require_rspec_core' for RSpec::Support:Module

Console log:

```
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Generators::Actions
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:17:in `<class:Base>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:15:in `<module:Generators>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:11:in `<module:Rails>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/my_zipcode_gem-0.1.3/lib/my_zipcode_gem.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/var/www/my-attorney-on-demand-web/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/my-attorney-on-demand-web/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/var/www/my-attorney-on-demand-web/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Error in the title is not the same as the error in console log. What is the exact error you're having trouble with?

Comment: what is your Ruby version (`ruby -v`) & Rails Version (`rails -v`)?